# Google Fusion map - how to pass parameter from external url

Tags: parameter-passing, google-fusion-tables

I would like to make external links to a page with an embeded google fusion map to open the page with a preset selection.  How can I pass the parameter in the url?

For instance, how could I make a link to this example page with the parameter passed to select the first county (Anderson County)?
http://www.texastribune.org/library/data/census-2010/

Comment: It's up to the page whether to parse a query string or not. The example in the link above does not seem to support that.  Are you the creator of that page?  It's simple to implement if you control that page.

Comment: I'm not the creator that page.  I will try to do a jsfiddle so we can control it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_FusionTablesLayer_linktoA.html?lat=31.636563&lng=-96.060020&zoom=7&type=m&tableid=2557947&tablequery=SELECT%20geometry%20from%202557947%20where%20county%20contains%20%27Anderson%20County%27) that uses that fusionTable and queries it for Anderson County with all the parameters specified in the URL.

Comment: Thank you!  I was just about to post a jsfiddle for it.  Here it is:
http://jsfiddle.net/lbriquet/UVdGC/